# Hold url param values while submitting form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**> Introduction**

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC project with EF6 and SQL server.

**> Explanation**

As you can see in the code below I have a controller with a method `Filter` to display some articles based on filtering, paging and sorting.

I display the articles in a table with for each article a checkbox. You can check these boxes and then choose out of 2 buttons: `Add` and `Remove`.

**Add:** set the selected articles as active ( field `IsActive = 1` in db )

**Remove:** set the selected articles as inactive ( field `IsActive = 0` in db )

Using jQuery I submit the form based on button and set a param state to identity if selected articles needs to be set active or inactive.

Al of this is working fine, I set a breakpoint in the `SetStateArticles` method and I get the selected id's and the state. The remaining code to handle this into the db needs to be written but this is not the issue. When I have set the form with a new url I lose my url values of the filtering. I want to keep this because I need to reload the page based on the filtering so that the user doesn't need to set the filtering, sorting and paging again.

How can I do this? How can I run a method of the controller but still remain on the same page or hold the values of the url param?

Like in webforms, you have just a postback, do something on the click event and return to the same page.

**> Code**

*Controller*

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    private ProsecMdmEntities db = new ProsecMdmEntities();

    // GET: Articles/Filter
    public ActionResult Filter(
            string supsf, string supso, int? supp,
            string artgsf, string artgso, int? artgp,
            string artsf, string artso, int? artp,
            int? supplier, int? articleGroup
        )
    {
        // do something.....
    }

    // POST: /Articles/SetStateArticles
    // Set the IsActive to true or false
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetStateArticles(int[] items, bool state)
    {
        return View();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

*View*

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Add items: set IsActive to true
        $('.add-items').click(function () {
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');
            $form.attr('action', '@Url.Action("SetStateArticles", "Articles", new { state = true })');
            $form.submit();
        });

        // Remove items: set IsActive to false
        $('.remove-items').click(function () {
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');
            $form.attr('action', '@Url.Action("SetStateArticles", "Articles", new { state = false })');
            $form.submit();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why not instead of making a new fresh call make a ajax call to action method and on success of that method you could direct to your page again.

Comment: I am using the web api also so yes this can be a solution, I will try this. Thanks for the headsup!

Comment: @Mivaweb Please check out my answer, I have provided two different solutions. Please let me know what you think and if you get any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok using the comments here I have solved this issue.

Below you can find the code that handles the post request to update the articles using my Web API 2:

**jQuery**

```
setItemState: function (state) {
    var values = $('input:checkbox[name=items]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $.post(uri_api + '/setstatearticles', { items: values, state: state.toString() })
        .done(function (data) {
            location.reload(true); // refresh the page after the changes
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        });
}
```

**Web API**

```
// POST: api/ArticlesApi/SetStateArticles
// Set the IsActive to true or false
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult SetStateArticles(JsArticleItemState jsItem)
{
    foreach (string item in jsItem.Items)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(item);

        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
        article.IsActive = int.Parse(jsItem.State) == 1;

        db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SignalR would be a perfect tool for this job!

Since you would be using SignalR there would be no page reload.

This would remove the need to attempt and hold the users position (Filtering/Sorting) on a page, since maintaining that code, I doubt that would be a 'nice' method.

You could do something like the following:

**Hub (Think of it as your controller)**

```
[HubName("nameOfHub")]
public class NameOfHub: Hub
{

    public void SetStateArticles(int[] items, bool state)
    {
        // All your logic for whatever you want to do, change a flag

        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).messageSuccess("What ever you want reported back");
    }
```

**View**

```
 var hub = $.connection.nameOfHub;

 hub.client.messageSuccess= function(message) {
     // Notify the user? This is once your SetStateArticles has finished
     // and we have called Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).messageSuccess in the Hub class
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
         console.log("Connected");
         $('.add-items').click(function () {
             hub.server.SetStateArticles(your params);
         });
     });
});
```

If you don't want to go down the SignalR route then I suggest `Ajax` calls.

**View**

```
$.ajax('@Url.Action("SetStateArticles", "Articles", new { state = true })')
.done(function (data) {
            // It's now updated so you can inform the user or do something else?
});
```